# Faster serial communication in C++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I am writing integers from a C++ program to a virtual COMM port. 
These integers are then being read from the COMM port by a piece of software.
I can get the data to pass at about 130Hz, but I would like to make things faster.
From observation, I believe that my C++ program is the limiting factor.

Is there any way I can make this faster?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
// Initialization
HANDLE hSerial;
hSerial = CreateFile( "COM3", GENERIC_WRITE, 0,0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);



DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};

GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate= 921600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);

COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=0;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0;
SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts);

DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
int position;
int newposition;

// loop
while(true){

position = newposition;

WriteFile(hSerial, &position, sizeof(position), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

if(kbhit()){
break;
};

};

return 0;
};
```

Comment: That source code doesn't even compile. You should come up with a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to demonstrate the problem, there's no way we can optimize code we can't see.

Comment: @Sneftel I wasn't expecting anyone to actually compile the code.  This is just a "mock up" that shows the part of the code that is relevant to serial communication. I am interacting with a number of different pieces of software in my actual script.

Comment: Your mockup is not adequate to diagnose any performance issues from your actual code.

Comment: @Sneftel I just made a couple edits. It compiles now, although it isn't written to really do anything. The type of advice I am looking for would be whether or not writing an integer to a serial port is efficient. Things like that.

Comment: There are ways of getting slightly higher performance IO, but writing a bunch of integers, one after the other, is going to be plenty fast for a serial port (well over 130 bps).

Comment: You couldn't possibly pick a worse way to do this.  But if you have no other way to interface with that program then you of course have few options.  Such a program would of course be written to operate at typical serial port speeds, glacially, the odds that you can make it go faster are very low.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you were right in saying that the serial port was not the limiting factor. Turns out I have some other problems to deal with.